# Как правильно использовать событие DOMContentLoaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, filter, lazyloading, ajax-load

Есть такой код:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseout mouseover', '.nbCatalogSectionContainer, form.nbFilter__form', function() {
            $('.lazy').lazy({
                bind: "event",
            });
});
```

Работает так: после отметки "галочки" в фильтре на странице обновляется список товаров.
И картинки этих появившихся товаров загружаются после движения курсора мыши.

Надо сделать так, чтобы картинки загружались "сами", автоматически после обновления списка отфильтрованных товаров.

https://p-td.ru/catalog/domashniy-tekstil/polotentsa/f/color-is-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9/a/

Comment: Извините, не очень понятна суть вопроса. Вопрос в  том, как правильно использовать `DOMContentLoaded` или сделать так чтобы картинки загружались при наведении на товар?

Comment: Чтобы картинки загружались сразу после обновления списка

https://p-td.ru/catalog/domashniy-tekstil/polotentsa/f/color-is-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9/a/

Comment: просто не используй lazy

Answer (score 0):

Если вам необходимо запускать "lazy" после полной загрузки контента страницы, то можно так:

```
window.onload = function() {
     $('.lazy').lazy({
                bind: "event",
            });
  };
```

Данный код подключит "lazy" только тогда, когда загрузилась вся страница, включая стили, картинки и другие ресурсы.

Comment: Так не работает

https://p-td.ru/catalog/domashniy-tekstil/polotentsa/f/color-is-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9/a/

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы картинки появлялись после каждого обновления списка